# Apache Beam Group by Aggregate Fields

Tags: java, apache-beam, avro, distributed-computing

I have a PCollection reading data from AvroIO. I want to apply aggregation such that after grouping by a specific key, I want to count unique counts of some fields within that group.

With normal Pig or SQL this is just applying groupby and doing a distinct count, but unable to properly understand how to do it in Beam.

So far I have been able to write this:

```
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File(options.getInputSchema()));

Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<GenericRecord> inputData= pipeline.apply(AvroIO.readGenericRecords(schema).from(options.getInput()));
PCollection<Row> filteredData = inputData.apply(Select.fieldNames("user_id", "field1", "field2"));
PCollection<Row> groupedData = filteredData.apply(Group.byFieldNames("user_id")                
                .aggregateField("field1",Count.perElement(),"out_field1")
                .aggregateField("field2",Count.perElement(),"out_field2"));
```

But this does not accept the arguments in aggregateField method.

Can someone help in providing the correct way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `Count.perElement()` with the `CountCombineFn()` fn which is a subclass of `CombineFn` class as seen [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.31.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/combiners.html#Count.PerElement)

```
filteredData.apply(Group.byFieldNames("user_id")                
.aggregateField("field1", CountCombineFn(), "out_field1")
.aggregateField("field2", CountCombineFn(), "out_field2"));
```